# Convert shp file or geojson to isobus iso-xml ISO 11783-10

Tags: geojson, shapefile, iso

has anyone had any experience with ISOBUS Iso-XML (ISO 11783-10)?

I would like to convert some geojson and/or shapefiles (.shp) to this format but am having trouble finding any information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specification of ISO 11783-10 is not free. You can buy the specification (google for *"ISO 11783-10"*), the documentation is high quality and affordable (I'm not affiliated in any way). The bought documents are distributed with some "license" and will be marked with your name, so buyers will be reluctant to share them. There are many concepts involved and details are cryptic, therefore you really need the specification to work with this format.

If you write source code encoding/decoding this format, it will depend on the specification. Distributing your source code + documentation might or might not infringe on the IP/license (I'm not a lawyer). Publishing detailed responses on this subject in open fora on the internet might or might not infringe.

There are quite some developers writing code which deals with ISO 11783-10, but I think the scarcity of freely available source code (e.g. on github) and open discussions on internet is a direct effect of the specification publication policy. It's sad because this domain is complex, has high impact, has many details which are very instance-specific (e.g. for a specific vehicle-manufacturer, accidental complexity), so open discussions and source code could improve productivity for many.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It is indeed sad that less code can be shared on this subject. I ended up buying the standard specification and writing my own code. It works but took much longer than I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Agleader software SMS Basic has the option to export shapefiles to ISOBUS format.